# Strange symbol lookup error in libstdc++

Tags: c++, linux

Trying to track down a segfault somewhere in MPI, I got this error:

```
./mpitest: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: bàþ;@ BC_
-------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun has exited due to process rank 2 with PID 8729 on ...
```

First, I'm used to getting lookup errors when the process is loaded if the library path is wrong. But those all happen before the process starts executing. This happened in the middle of the output from the test. Shouldn't all symbols be resolved by the runtime loader before the process starts?

Second, that symbol looks like garbage. It's certainly not a normal mangled C++ symbol.

Is it possible for memory corruptions (since I am tracking a segfault, it's likely there's something like that going on) to corrupt symbols like this?

This was compiled with icpc 12.0.3 20110309 on a Linux 2.6.18-194.32.1.el5 x86_64 machine.

Comment: Is it possible that your process loads symbols dynamically? In that case, a memory corruption could be the reason for such garbage. Have you tried [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?

Comment: @Jonas: Well, **my** code doesn't. I have no idea whether OpenMPI/Boost::MPI does. The problem with running Valgrind is that just calling MPI_Init_Thread gives approximately 25,000 errors, so it's hard to know if any of them is the cause.

Answer (score 2):

OpenMPI loads plugins as dynamic shared object at runtime when MPI_INIT is called. See this [FAQ](http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=building#avoid-dso). Therefore symbol lookup happens at that time. So it looks to me that your OpenMPI's libmpi_cxx.so was built against a different libstdc++ than what is available or found at runtime. on the system.

You can either rebuild OpenMPI, or if the correct libstdc++ is somewhere on your system (not /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6), you can adjust your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Also, try setting LD_DEBUG=files to see if you are in fact load 2 different libstdc++'s.